# what is the correct syntax to use when testing if a posted form value contains text equal to XX php

Tags: php

I'm trying to write an if statement to test if a posted form value is equal to xx

```
 $field = $_POST['myfield'];

 if($field == 'Hello world') {

 / /do something 

 }
```

Is this correct..?

Thanks

Comment: it's `$_POST` not `$_Post`

Comment: corrected - will the rest work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes.but first check with it is set or not

```
$field =(isset($_POST['myfield']))?$_POST['myfield']:'';
    if($field == 'Hello world') {

     / /do something 

     }
```

Comment: yes but I'm testing if the form has been submitted...? thanks